# Fixing "undefined index" errors in PHP

Tags: php

```
if ((!$_GET['month']) && (!$_GET['year'])) {
  $month = date ("n");
  $year = date ("Y");
} else {
  $month = $_GET['month'];
  $year = $_GET['year'];
}
```

it shows `Notice: Undefined index: month in....` .

I know that if I use `error_reporting(null);` above the code, the notice will not appear, but is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: `isset` `array_key_exists` and `empty` are your friends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array element does not exist, you get the notice since you are trying to *access* a non-existent element. You need to use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) to check it (those are not functions but language constructs so it's not considered accessing those elements). Since you probably never have empty/zero years/months, `empty` makes more sense; but you could also use `!isset()`, then `0` and empty strings will be allowed, too.

```
if(empty($_GET['month']) || empty($_GET['year'])) {
    $month = date('n');
    $year = date('Y');
}
else {
    $month = (int)$_GET['month'];
    $year = (int)$_GET['year'];
}
```

However, it might make more sense to check those two variables separately:

```
$month = empty($_GET['month']) ? date('n') : $_GET['month'];
$year = empty($_GET['year']) ? date('Y') : $_GET['year'];
```

Comment: Showing how to properly do the logic he wants might be good.  `if (!empty(...) && !(empty(...)) { $month = ...; $year = ...; } else { $month = date('n'); $year = date('Y'); }`

Comment: $month = empty(intval($_GET['month'])) ? date('n') : $_GET['month'];

Comment: @askovpen intval always returns at least (int)0 so it would never be empty

Comment: @Corbin: True, but I highly doubt he wants that as it could still leave him with a notice in case only one of the values is missing.

Comment: The way I've written it, it would not be possible for that block of code to generate a notice for an undefined index.  Either both indexes are defined, or neither are accessed.

Comment: @askovpen intval() would throw an undefined index notice if the month key did not exist.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone empty() considers 0 empty.  (And "0" interestingly enough.)

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently have it is check both at once and if one fails change both, perhaps it would be better to preset the month & date and then change if params are passed. Plus it would be a good idea to check there numeric. Else a string may break your code further along

```
<?php 
$month = date ("n");
$year = date ("Y");
if (isset($_GET['month']) && is_numeric($_GET['month'])) {
    $month = $_GET['month'];
}
if (isset($_GET['year']) && is_numeric($_GET['year'])) {
    $year = $_GET['year'];
}

//Or better yet
$month = (isset($_GET['month']) && is_numeric($_GET['month']))?$_GET['month']:date("n");
$year = (isset($_GET['year']) && is_numeric($_GET['year']))?$_GET['year']:date("Y");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `empty()` or `isset()` to check if a variable has been defined.

```
if ( empty($_GET['month']) || empty($_GET['year']) ) {
   $month = date ("n");
   $year = date ("Y");
} else {
   $month = $_GET['month'];
   $year = $_GET['year'];
}
```

Comment: Check your logic.  What if month is empty but not year?  Bam.  Undefined index 'month'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $month = date('n');
 $year = date('Y');
 if (isset($_GET['month'])) {
   $month=$_GET['month'];
 }
 if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
   $year=$_GET['year'];
 }
```

Comment: yeah, had realised as soon as I posted it. Corrected now

Comment: Still has a problem.  This will set only the month if both the month and year are set. (And a mismatched `(` on line 3 and 5)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `if(isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['year']))` in your if block